# Ajax URL not correct with subfolder implemented

Tags: ajax, laravel, url

I implemented my project in a subfolder. I am putting it in /var/www/html/subfolder

The link to my subfolder project looks like this

> https://mytestingsite.com/subfolder

Ajax

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/subfolder/testroute",
  data: data,  
  dataType: json
});
```

When i call an ajax, my url will be

> url : "/subfolder/testroute"

But the url return https://mytestingsite.com/testroute

I exptected the url return as https://mytestingsite.com/subfolder/testroute

I found that if i put my url as

> url : "/subfolder/subfolder/testroute"

Then the url only will return https://mytestingsite.com/subfolder/testroute

Is anything wrong with my route?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var baseurl = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host;

$.ajax({
  url: baseurl + "/subfolder/testroute",
  data: data,  
  dataType: json
});
```